# Switch Primary Display when existing is unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, settings, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to automatically make the secondary monitor as primary, when the primary monitor is unresponsive?

I Have Dual monitor setup one is my laptop screen (secondary) and the other is an external monitor (primary), when i switch off my external monitor, the laptop screen stays as secondary monitor. I need to change  the secondary monitor to primary when this happens. I am on Ubuntu OS, and i don't see any option to do this in Displays setting.

**Note**: The secondary monitor changes to primary when the HDMI connection is removed.